# $ firefox /usr/lib/firefox/firefox: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /usr/lib/firefox/firefox)

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, firefox

Getting error on Manjaro after upgrading firefox:

```
$ firefox
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /usr/lib/firefox/firefox)
```

```
$ sudo pacman -Qo /lib/libstdc++.so.6


/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 is owned by gcc-libs 11.2.0-4
```

How do I fix?

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Error is on server side : bad package
Downgrade it !

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/firefox-version-100-0-0-1-not-launching/111174/29